# How to read two lines from a file in perl

Tags: perl

I am wondering why I can't seem to take in 2 lines in Perl
A snippet of my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open my $fh, "<", "data.txt" or die;

$line1 = <$fh>;
$line2 = <$fh>;

print $line1."\n";
print $line2."\n";

while(1){
    @rows = <$fh>;
    print "$rows[$e]";
    $e++;
    print "$rows[$e]";
}
```

This is the kind of data I have in Data.txt

```
  5000    5000    12497500    0
  5000    5000    33258530    0
  5000    13    51822    0
  5000    13    130147    0
  5000    28    75016    0
  5000    28    181343    0
  5000    5000    4999    4999
  5000    5000    12580635    4999
```

I have looked around for possible solutions, I found some interesting leads here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=620077, particularly these ones

```
my $fh = open("file");

for =$fh->$line1,$line2 {
  # do whatever with the two lines
}
```

and

```
for (;;) {
   my $line1 = <$fh>;
   last if not defined $line1;

   my $line2 = <$fh>;
   last if not defined $line2;

   ...
}
```

Could I also ask what `for =$fh->$line1,$line2` why is there a =$ and why does it not work or how does it work?

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

**UPDATE**
Alright, so I might be missing on something, but this is the operation I wanted to do from the lines

```
while(1){
    print '-'x50 . "\n";
    my $line1 = <$fh>;

    if($line1 =~ /^\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s*$/){
        my $A1 = $1;
        my $B1 = $2;
        my $C1 = $3;
        my $D1 = $4;
    }
    last unless defined $line1;

    my $line2 = <$fh>;

    if($line2 =~ /^\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s+(\d)\s*$/){
        my $A2 = $1;
        my $B2 = $2;
        my $C2 = $3;
        my $D2 = $4;
    }
    last unless defined $line2;

    my @type = ("AL", "PL", "RL", "AA", "PA", "RA", "AB", "PB", "RB", "AR", "PR", "RR", "AS", "PS", "RS", "AV", "PV", "RV");


    print("For $type[$i]\n");
    print("Node : $A1\n");
    print("Depth : $B1\n");
    print("Nb : $C1\n");
    print("Nb+s : $C1+$C2\n");
    print("Nk : $A1\n");
    print("Nu : $A1/6\n");
    print("Average number of comparisons is $C2/(7/6*$A1)\n");
    $i++;
}
print '--- END ---'."\n";
```

This is based on xxFelixxxx's response

Comment: Been a while since I've written perl, but `while(1){` looks like an infinite loop with no break. I'm assuming that's intentional, but just in case... heads up. Also, where's `$e` initialized?

Comment: `for =$fh->$line1,$line2` is using `perl6` which should be considered a different, but related language to `perl` aka `perl5`.

Comment: Add `use strict;` to all of your scripts, and fix all of the issues it complains about, this will lead to less buggy code.

Comment: yeah while(1) was intentional, and sorry $e was initialised at the top but I took it out by mistake. @ParthianShot

Comment: ah i see regarding the for =$... but would it be possible to do it in perl5? - nvm saw your answer at the bottom sorry!@xxfelixxx

Comment: @xxfelixxx hey, I updated my question, it'd be much appreciated if you could take an extra look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, you call `@rows = <$fh>;` which will take all of the lines of your file and put them into `@rows`.  The next time through the while loop, it will attempt to do the same thing...but there are no more lines left, so `@rows` will be empty.  So if you need all of the rows, grab them outside of your `while` loop.  If you just need 2 lines at a time, you can just grab 2 rows inside your loop and check that they are not empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "data.txt" or die "Unable to open data.txt for reading : $!";

while(1) {
    print '-'x50 . "\n";
    my $line1 = <$fh>;
    last unless defined $line1;
    print "ODD  LINE $. : $line1";

    my $line2 = <$fh>;
    last unless defined $line2;
    print "EVEN LINE $. : $line2";
}
print '--- SUCCESS ---' . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------
ODD  LINE 1 :   5000    5000    12497500    0
EVEN LINE 2 :   5000    5000    33258530    0
--------------------------------------------------
ODD  LINE 3 :   5000    13    51822    0
EVEN LINE 4 :   5000    13    130147    0
--------------------------------------------------
ODD  LINE 5 :   5000    28    75016    0
EVEN LINE 6 :   5000    28    181343    0
--------------------------------------------------
ODD  LINE 7 :   5000    5000    4999    4999
EVEN LINE 8 :   5000    5000    12580635    4999
--------------------------------------------------
--- SUCCESS ---
```

**Update**

In your updated version, you have a scoping issue, in that the construct of

```
if (...) { 
    my ($foo) = 123;
}
print $foo; # <--- out of scope
```

means that the rest of your code will not see the variables `$A1,$B1,$C1,$D1`.  The use of regular expressions is not necessary and can be more clearly expressed using a `split` on whitespace and a `grep` on digits, for sanity checking.  The construct of `my @foo = ("abc","def","ghi");` is more perlishly expressed as `my @foo = qw( abc def ghi );`

Here is an updated version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "data.txt" or die "Unable to open data.txt for reading : $!";

my @types = qw(AL PL RL AA PA RA AB PB RB AR PR RR AS PS RS AV PV RV);

while(1) {
    print '-'x50 . "\n";
    # TODO: better names than a,b,c,d
    my ($A1,$B1,$C1,$D1) = get_row($fh);
    last unless defined $A1;

    my ($A2,$B2,$C2,$D2) = get_row($fh);
    last unless defined $A2;

    my $type = shift @types; # Pull one off the front
    defined $type
        or die "No more types left!";

    my $Nb_plus_s = $C1 + $C2;
    # sprintf("%0.2f", 123.456789) -> 123.46   # round to 2 decimals
    my $Nu = sprintf("%0.2f", $A1 / 6);
    my $avg_comparisons = sprintf("%0.2f", $C2/(7/6*$A1));

    print "For $type\n";
    print "Node  : $A1\n";
    print "Depth : $B1\n";
    print "Nb    : $C1\n";
    print "Nb+s  : $Nb_plus_s\n";
    print "Nk    : $A1\n";
    print "Nu    : $Nu\n";
    print "Average number of comparisons is $avg_comparisons\n";
}
print '--- SUCCESS ---' . "\n";

sub get_row {
    my ($file_handle) = @_;
    my $line = <$file_handle>;
    return unless defined $line;

    # Split on whitespace, keep only numbers
    my @data = grep {/\d/} split /\s+/, $line;

    # Check that we have 4 columns of data
    (4 == scalar @data)
        or die "Cannot understand line: '$line'";

    return(@data);
}
```

**New Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------
For AL
Node  : 5000
Depth : 5000
Nb    : 12497500
Nb+s  : 45756030
Nk    : 5000
Nu    : 833.33
Average number of comparisons is 5701.46
--------------------------------------------------
For PL
Node  : 5000
Depth : 13
Nb    : 51822
Nb+s  : 181969
Nk    : 5000
Nu    : 833.33
Average number of comparisons is 22.31
--------------------------------------------------
For RL
Node  : 5000
Depth : 28
Nb    : 75016
Nb+s  : 256359
Nk    : 5000
Nu    : 833.33
Average number of comparisons is 31.09
--------------------------------------------------
For AA
Node  : 5000
Depth : 5000
Nb    : 4999
Nb+s  : 12585634
Nk    : 5000
Nu    : 833.33
Average number of comparisons is 2156.68
--------------------------------------------------
--- SUCCESS ---
```

Comment: Cheers! Thanks a lot :) This clears up a lot of misunderstandings I had! and yeah the naming wasn't just abcde but it was a data which I just decided to edit to make things a little easier :)

Answer (score 1):

`$line1` and `$line2` read the first two lines from the file. Problem is in the loop:

```
@rows = <$fh>;
```

This reads all the remaining files into the array. In list context, which array assignment imposes, you always read everything. You can try instead

```
while (! eof $fh) {
    my $line1 = <$fh>;
    push @rows, "Odd: $line1";
    last if eof $fh;

    my $line2 = <$fh>;
    push @rows, "Even: $line2";
}
print "@rows";
```

It uses [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) to detect the end of input.